# How can I pass an class instance into another class so it can be modified?

Tags: java

```
public class Player {
    private int hp = 100;
    //with appropriate getters and setters, constructors etc.
}

public class Main{
    Player player1 = new Player();
    Player player2 = new Player();
    //etc.

    fightMonster(player1); //<--- I want to pass player1 to keep track of HP
}

public class fightMonster(something about player1){ //not sure what to put inside the ();
    player1.setHp(player1.getHp - 10); //monster attacks and does 10 dmg
}
```

Currently I can't find a way to pass the instance of the Player class `player1` to my `fightMonster` method since it's in a different class. I want to pass the whole `player1` class because it will eventually include that players inventory, experience, previous hp, etc. 
The only way I can think of doing this is splitting out each line of `player1` like passing `int hp` through and going back into `main` and using `player1.setHp(int hp)`. This does not solve more complex applications though (inventory items gained from fighting, experience etc.).

Even if I could create a new instance of the `Player` class like

`Player currentPlayer = new Player();`

and then somehow back in `Main` match all the values together...

This is my first time posting, please help!

Comment: What exactly will the fightmonster method be doing? Is it possible to just define a method inside the player class called fight monster?

Comment: Trying to explain the concept of argument passing to someone who evidently does not understand it is not the kind of specific, narrow question this site is for.

Comment: @Raedwald I understand the concept just now how to pass this specific type: Class. That's what I'm asking about since I can't find it anywhere on this site or specifically in google or the other Java classes I'm taking.

Perhaps you could help the discussion instead of being derogatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you want to execute a method, that has one parameter.
You could have something like this:

```
 String variable = "Hello";
 doSomething(variable);

 public void doSomething(String variable){}
```

The parameters of the method you are calling must be of the same type of the variable you pass when you call the method.

So in your case I would suggest:

```
 public class Main {
      Player player1 = new Player(); //You create a new Player
      FightMonster actions = new FightMonster();

      player1 = actions.getHit(player1); //You call the method "getHit" and pass the values of player1
 }

 public class FightMonster {
      //The value of "player" its the same value of "player1" that you pass when you called this method
      public Player getHit(Player player) {
           player.setHp(player.getHp - 10); //You change the hp of the player
           return player; //And return the new value of the player
      }
 }
```

After you return the value, the player which was passed when you called the method, will have the new value returned.

Comment: brackets after the class name?? `public class fightMonster(){...}` Correct it.

Comment: Thank you! I kept using `Class player` to pass it instead of `Player player` but now I understand. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Player{

    public static void main(String [] a){

    Player player1 = new Player();
    Player player2 = new Player();

    //You can either use constructor of FightMonster class to pass your object reference
    FightMonster object = new FightMonster(player1);

    //or you can setup another method in FightMonster which will receive the reference of the player class
    object.passReference(player1);
    }        
}
class FightMonster{

    Player player;
    public FightMonster(Player player){

          this.player = player;
          //Now, In this class you can use player reference
    }
    public void passReference(Player player){
          this.player = player;
    }
}
```

If the class `FightMonster` - to which you are passing the reference of `Player` class - will not be used by any other classes, then in that case you can also make it an inner class. 
e.g. Here I have created a method local inner class which is defined inside `main` method.

```
public class Player{

    public static void main(String [] a){

    Player player1 = new Player();
    Player player2 = new Player();

    class FightMonsterInner{
        public void displayInformation(){
            //here, you can access variables and instance defined in outer class.
        }
    }

    FightMonsterInner innerObject = new FightMonsterInner();
    innerObject.displayInformation();

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is there a specific reason for fightMonster method to be in another class? I would do something like...

```
   public class Player {
     private int hp = 100;
     //with appropriate getters and setters, constructors etc.
     public void fightMonster() {
          this.setHp(this.hp - 10);
     }
    }
```

... then you just need to call `p1.fightMonster();` to get the proper result. Hope it helps!